# Type.FullName prefixed by Assembly name

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about VB.Net.  I normally use CSharp.

The Type.FullName property seems to include the name of the assembly but the docs say that it should not:

Type.FullName Property

...The fully qualified name of the Type, including the namespace of the Type but not the assembly;

```
''Class1.vb -- compiled into assembly VBLib
Namespace Space1
    Public Class Class1

    End Class
End Namespace

''Class2.cs
namespace Space2
{
    class Class2
    {
    }
}

''Program.cs

using Space2;
using VBLib.Space1;  // Need to prefix the namespace with the assembly name?

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type t1 = typeof(Class1);
    Type t2 = typeof(Class2);

    Console.WriteLine("t1 = " + t1.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine("t2 = " + t2.FullName);
}
```

Output:

> t1 = VBLib.Space1.Class1
>
> t2 = Space2.Class2

I am using reflection and trying to get some consistent behavior between CSharp and VB full type names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you specify the full namespace including the default namespace of the project in the file. Usually, the default namespace of the project is the first part of the namespace that is specified in the file, but you could also specify a namespace that is independent from the default namespace of the project.

In contrast, in a VB.NET project, the namespace that you specify in a file is put after the default namespace of a project. So if you put the namespace `Space1`in your file, the types are located in `VBLib.Space1` if the default namespace of your project is `VBLib`.

As the default namespace of a project is usually the same as the assembly name, it seems as if VB.NET places the assembly name in front of the namespace. To test this, you can change the default namespace of your project so that it differs from your assembly name.

Both approaches have their pros and cons. C# on the one hand is more flexible, but you have to change all files if you want to change the default namespace. In VB.NET, changing the default namespace is easy, but you are less flexible in your choice of the namespace as the default namespace is always the first part.

Comment: Excellent response!  I knew I was just missing something.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, VB doesn't have a 'default' namespace, it has a 'root' namespace.  This is how it is labelled in the project settings.